# what reliable method to save huge numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I saved some arrays using **numpy.savez_compressed()**. One of the arrays is gigantic, it has the shape (120000,7680), type *float32*.
Trying to load the array gave me the error below (message caught using *Ipython*).
Is seems like this is a *Numpy* limitation:
[Numpy: apparent memory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027513/numpy-apparent-memory-error)
What are other ways to save such a huge array? (I had problems with *cPickle* as well)

```
In [5]: t=numpy.load('humongous.npz')
In [6]: humg = (t['arr_0.npy'])


/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
229             if bytes.startswith(format.MAGIC_PREFIX):
230                 value = BytesIO(bytes)
--> 231                 return format.read_array(value)
232             else:
233                 return bytes

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/format.pyc in read_array(fp)
456             # way.

457             # XXX: we can probably chunk this to avoid the memory hit.

--> 458             data = fp.read(int(count * dtype.itemsize))
459             array = numpy.fromstring(data, dtype=dtype, count=count)
460 

SystemError: error return without exception set
```

System: Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit, Python 2.7, numpy 1.6.1

Comment: Have you tried to close the ipython session you used to write the array (freeing the memory used by the array itself) and later try to load the array in a new session?  As I think of it, also a `del(big_one)` should, _should_ return the memory to the system.

Comment: i generally tend to use [joblib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/joblib) for dumping large arrays and never had any problems with it. Joblib also comes with [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) so if you are using scikit then you don't have to install an extra package.

Comment: how much ram do you have? (with float32, you take about 3.7 Gb ram for the array)

Comment: @ng0323 a good option for you would be to use `np.memmap()` arrays, which work directly with the data stored in the disk (with small chuncks of memory allocated)

Comment: @gboffi same problem with a fresh ipython session. I have 12Gb RAM. System monitor shows 2.3 Gb initially and increases gradually to about 6 Gb while line [6] runs, then the error message appears.

Comment: I've been using `joblib` so far. It compresses numpy arrays pretty well.